"Unimplemented component" while using expo-linear-gradient with Expo SDK 52 beta
I'm trying to use the expo-linear-gradient package with expo@~52.0.0-preview.21.
When I run yarn dlx expo install --check it tells me all my dependencies are OK.
When I run the app on iOS I get the error: Unimplemented component: <ViewManagerAdapter_ExpoLinearGradient>.

The rest of the application keeps working, only the "box" where the linear gradient should be shows this error message.
I'm running the app with yarn ios -c to ensure no cache is used.
These are my expo dependencies:
    "expo": "~52.0.0-preview.21",
    "expo-blur": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-constants": "~17.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-haptics": "~14.0.0",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~14.0.1",
    "expo-linking": "~7.0.2",
    "expo-router": "~4.0.0-preview.14",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.29.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
    "expo-symbols": "~0.2.0",
    "expo-system-ui": "~4.0.2",
    "expo-web-browser": "~14.0.0",

What should I do?
